# Using margins command in r with fixed effects

Tags: r, margins

I'm trying to use the margins command in R to calculate the marginal effect of a variable in a continuous x categorical (internet use x organizational membership) interaction for different levels of the categorical variable (organizational membership). However, the margins command keeps giving me an error because I have country dummies in my regression for country fixed effects. Is there a way to circumvent this error?

```
library(survey)
library(margins)
wvs <- read.csv("WVS_VI_FINAL.csv")
wvsdata <- wvs[c(433:585)]
autocr <- select(filter(wvsdata, POLITYIV<=5), c(COUNTRY, HIGH_RISK_PROTEST_BIN, INTERNET_RC, INTERNET_DAILY_BIN, INTERNET_WEEKLY_BIN, ICT_DAILY_BIN, ICT_WEEKLY_BIN, FORM_ORG, POLIT_INT_RC, FIN_SATIS_RC, INCOME_QUINT_RC, ATTEND_CHURCH_RC, GENDER_RC, MARITAL_RC, CHILDREN_RC, EDUC_BAS, STUDENT_RC, EMPLOYED_RC, AGE_RC, COUNTRY_RC, S019))

autoc$FORM_ORG <- as.factor(autoc$FORM_ORG)
autoc$LEISURE_ORG <- as.factor(autoc$LEISURE_ORG)
autoc$ACTIVIST_ORG_NR <- as.factor(autoc$ACTIVIST_ORG_NR)
autoc$INCOME_QUINT <- as.factor(autoc$INCOME_QUINT_RC)
autoc$EDUC_BAS_1 <- as.factor(autoc$EDUC_BAS)
autoc$COUNTRY <- as.factor(autoc$COUNTRY_RC)

svydata1 <- svydesign(id= ~1, weight= ~S019, data=autoc)

options(survey.lonely.psu="adjust")

summary(svydata1)

mysvylogit2e <- svyglm(HIGH_RISK_PROTEST_BIN ~ INTERNET_RC + FORM_ORG + POLIT_INT_RC + FIN_SATIS_RC + INCOME_QUINT + ATTEND_CHURCH_RC + GENDER_RC + MARITAL_RC + CHILDREN_RC + EDUC_BAS_1 + STUDENT_RC + EMPLOYED_RC + AGE_RC + INTERNET_RC:FORM_ORG + COUNTRY, design = svydata1, family=quasibinomial(link=logit))

marge <- margins(mysvylogit2e, design=svydata1)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(tt, data = newdata, xlev = object$xlevels) : factor COUNTRY has new level Argentina

So I'm not sure how best to incorporate the fixed effect into the margins command. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `margins` does not support `plm` objects, no panel models